# Connectiong Remotely To Windows Server 2008r2 Core DNS_INFO_NO_RECORDS

Tags: dns, windows-server-2008-r2, server-core

I made a domain on a Windows CoreServer 2008r2 and I am trying to connect to it remotely using a Windows 10 VM. When I try and connect to it, I am getting an error saying my domain could not be contact, when I expand for details it explain this..

"No records found for given DNS query."
(error code 0x0000251D DNS_INFO_NO_RECORDS)

The query was for the SRV record for _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.my.domain

Is there anything you can suggest that I do to try and fix this?

Comment: This really isn't a programming question, despite the bounty. "Connecting" to a server can mean several things; how are you attempting it??